# Issues with Do/While loop in java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

This code is a snippet from a Blackjack game I'm making. No matter what I enter, the program never breaks out of a loop.

```
boolean bool = true;
do{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = kb.next();
    if(choice == "Hit" || choice == "hit") {
        String action = "hit";
        bool = false;
    } else if(choice == "Stay" || choice == "stay") {
        String action = "stay";
        bool = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Do not recognize response. Retry.");
    }
} while (bool == true);
```

What normally happens:
http://puu.sh/87KZk.png

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't compare strings in Java using `==`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing strings with ==. In Java we compare strings with `.equals()` instead.

You can do something like this:

```
boolean bool = true;
do {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = kb.next();
    if(choice.equals("Hit") || choice.equals("hit")) {
        String action = "hit";
        bool = false;
    } else if(choice.equals("Stay") || choice.equals("stay")) {
        String action = "stay";
        bool = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Do not recognize response. Retry.");
    }
} while (bool == true);
```

I also formatted some parts of your code for clarity. 
As suggested in the comments below, you can also use `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare string regardless of their capitalization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also worth mentioning, [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as it lets me.